# Amazon Cloudfront access denied

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I created web distribution and checked restrict access. This is [image: screenshot]

For creating signed url I use the following code:

```
 var pathToKey = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
                ManagerApiConfiguration.Config.Aws.AmazonCloudFrontSecretFilePath);

             var fileInfo = new FileInfo(pathToKey);

            var url = AmazonCloudFrontUrlSigner.GetCannedSignedURL(
                AmazonCloudFrontUrlSigner.Protocol.http,
                ManagerApiConfiguration.Config.Aws.AmazonCloudFrontResourcePath,
                fileInfo,
                key,
                ManagerApiConfiguration.Config.Aws.AmazonCloudFrontAccessKey,
                DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)
                );
```

All variables are filled correctly. I checked and url looks like:

> http://XXXXXXXX.cloudfront.net/Themes/Case
>   Covers/International/img1.jpg?Expires=1453886647&Signature=KEpC4ej4f00ir5KMWmqYs3dD64hRQ1~9609HvGk7KL8JjxNf207n99QXNtmSSXeu5JWH9wRqGfRzil76TH7oPl3NpTJwVhEcaty1E8mODrVIKaoFF-4Sq~KhvPk4Z164UZhaEueroggtjHHfFbzByVQ7iDkU-qCXgl1JPjjonPvExIH3~4QHh2GR1oiQDlZolgyA1Dts7JQglouKJ11-hhqRxZKD7FQMnE3adKGcnxvzd0Fx6x1Bnqy41nTGUPLdc~PrX~ZgSLVQgO7EKJ7wMiK0ZUKRthhoRT1LqHFKotNyJdxFgXlrmENJpklt5Pezm6KM7Y~E2Mo~zpqBJJ7OYQ__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJEOHJXFJHBUONVPQ

But I get error : access denied.
I have policy for the backet also:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket_name/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Where is a problem. Thanks.

PS. If I uncheck restrict access then all works fine.